# Can i use an IF statement in a foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I'm trying to create a constraint to add a foreign key to a column. Inside the constraint i'm trying to use a IF statement to set that when the column "Tipo" of my table is equal to 'E' or 'e'  then the column id_cliente_fornecedor must be linked to the table "Fornecedores" or else, if the column "Tipo" is equal to 'S' or 's', the column id_cliente_fornecedor must be linked to the table clientes.

I already have a Check constraint on the column "Tipo" to set the allowed values to be only 'S','s','E' and 'e';

```
alter table francisco.movimentacao
add constraint fk_clifor
FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente_fornecedor)
references begin
if((movimentacao.tipo = 'E') or (movimentacao.tipo = 'e')) then 
    francisco.fornecedores(id)
    else
    francisco.clientes(id)
end;
```

Can anybody help me? Is this possible?

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle 11.2! Thanks man, it worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11g+, you can do this with virtual columns.

```
alter table francisco.movimentacao
    add key_e as (case when tip in ('E', 'e') then id_cliente_fornecedor end);

alter table francisco.movimentacao
    add key_x as (case when tip not in ('E', 'e') then id_cliente_fornecedor end);

alter table francisco.movimentacao
    add constraint fk_key_e foreign key (key_e) references francisco.fornecedores(id);

alter table francisco.movimentacao
    add constraint fk_key_x foreign key (key_x) references francisco.clientes(id);
```

Comment: In oracle, are the nulls not constrained by the foreign key?

Comment: @RBarryYoung . . . Foreign keys can take on `NULL` values.